# Synchronized charts or multiple charts like Highcharts in Android

Tags: android, charts, highcharts, mpandroidchart

How could we achieve `Synchronized charts` in `Android`.

For my web page I've used `Highcharts` API. Is there any similar thing for Android. I've checked various libraries mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10716564/2820534) but didn't find any which will match the requirement.

I don't want combined charts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31868729/2820534) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056095/mpandroidchart-combined-chart?rq=1). I'm looking for Synchronized charts.

Is there any library which will meet the requirement or Should I go with `webView` (It's a worst case for me)

Is it possible with `MPAndroidChart`?

**EDIT**:

Resultant chart should be like the Charts given in [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts) page

**Sample**:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Motto is not just to draw the 3 charts. The Aim is to synchronize them. Synchronise means all the 3 charts have same x-axis(values), on click at any point in these charts the plot at that particular point should be highlighted in all the charts. I'm sure I didn't explain it properly. Kindly check this [link](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts) and hover the graph

Comment: please specify that which type of chart you want to prepare, I mean image or something that can give a proper idea.

Comment: @DeepPatel Updated. 
Now, I'm trying to draw 2 line charts, place it one beneath another, use same x-axis data set and try some logic on markers, I mean on click at any point. Don't know where it leads to. I'm trying that now

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: Related question [MPAndroidChart: Have one graph mirror the zoom/swipes on a sister graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28521004/mpandroidchart-have-one-graph-mirror-the-zoom-swipes-on-a-sister-graph)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when clicked on chart 1 get the X and Y points and highlight them on chart 2. Same with 2nd chart.

```
    lineChart1.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h)
        {
            lineChart2.highlightValue(e.getX(),e.getY(),0,false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected()
        {
        }
    });


    lineChart2.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h)
        {
            lineChart1.highlightValue(e.getX(),e.getY(),0,false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {
        }
    });
```

**NOTE** set the last argument to false so that it doesn't call the listener again and again. If this is not set then it results to deadlock.

Answer (score 2):

The [sample app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xxmassdeveloper.mpchartexample) has a good display of the features available to you "out of the box" with MPAndroidChart.

As you can see, there is an example of multiple charts inside a ListView which seems to be close to your requirement.

[image: 3 charts one on top of the other as per OP's requirement]

Likewise, the [source code](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) is available on GitHub for you to inspect and see if it has the available classes and methods for you to do what you want out of the box.

At the same time, you should understand that it is often unrealistic to expect to find a library that will exactly suit an unusual requirement from mere configuration alone. Free and open source libraries often provision for extension and customisation and MPAndroidChart is no exception. As a professional software engineer, or as an aspiring one, you should be willing and prepared to program that yourself.

In your particular case, it seems you want some kind of co-ordination between the charts. So if you click on one of them then the `MarkerView` appears on all at the same xIndex in the DataSet.

To attempt this, you would start by looking at the code for [`OnChartGestureListener`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/a3c1fe6bbf7d48b79b42b3a447f946af850d86f0/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/listener/OnChartGestureListener.java). A solution can be obtained through using [event-driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). You would set up 3 implementations of `OnChartGestureListener` which would use events to transmit the current gesture to a mediator who then triggers the same gestures on the other two charts. For example, inside `OnChartGestureListener` there is a method to implement called:

```
void onChartScale(MotionEvent var1, float var2, float var3);
```

Your implementation would look something like this:

```
@Override
void onChartScale(MotionEvent var1, float var2, float var3) {
    //transmit event to mediator 
    //handle event for this chart
}
```

If this is too difficult then you will have to stick with Highcharts inside a `WebView` as you have cogently suggested yourself. However, be aware that the performance inside the `WebView` will not be as good as using a library that renders to canvas directly.

In short, it is *possible*, although difficult, to accomplish what you want using `MPAndroidChart` and no "out-of-the-box" solution is available.

Comment: I've done till getting the charts and plotting the axis point. But I'm stuck with the markers. The previous version of `MPAndroidChart` was much convenient for me. Now I'm literally struggling with it. But however I understood that this task requires more effort and can be achieved with the guidance provided by you

Comment: gesture and all is fine, but how do I call two instances of Marker at the same time

Comment: I think you will have to use `getHighlighter` on the target chart and then `updateHighlighted`

Comment: inside `onValueSelected` I'm getting the x and y co-ordinates on which we've clicked. Now I've to call a marker and say it to show a marker at those co-ordinates in remaining charts. How do I call Marker manually?

Comment: I would suggest posting an event that goes to a `MarkerManager` class. The `MarkerManager` would then use the `Highlighter` of the charts to set the marker view.

Comment: Task completed. `highlightValue` with required arguments did the trick

Answer (score -2):

You can surely make it using [MPAndroidCharts](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library.

Go for 1> LineChart (with legend, simple design) for **Speed** 
2> LineChart (cubic lines) / (gradient fill) for **Elevation , Heart**

While Using gradientFill apply this to eliminate dashed line and draw a straight line:

```
    lineDataSet.enableDashedLine(0f, 0f, 0f);
    lineDataSet.enableDashedHighlightLine(0f, 0f, 0f);
```

Comment: I'm done with Line charts @DeepPatel. My question is 'How to synchronise them'.